# Can raspberry pi flash Raspbian to Android

Tags: video, android

Is it possible for Raspberry pi to flash Noobs to any Android device? I have no device I am actively trying this on yet. If it is possible I a Nexus device running Android is what I would try to work with. I want more control over my Android.

Comment: I posted this question and then found a post about porting. I am going to try that too.

Comment: Android and Raspbian are incompatible operating systems.